# Cannot resolve Constants.REQUEST_CONTEXT_ATTR in PrimeFaces 4.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to update GUI. It's showing timer. The timer is working fine. But the page or component that include timer must be update always. Then I can display live timer. 
So I need to update component. But `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()` is pointing `NullPointerException`. I searched and found below.

```
((RequestContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(Constants.REQUEST_CONTEXT_ATTR);)
```

But `Constants.REQUEST_CONTEXT_ATTR` is not resolving. On the other hand, coloring red `REQUEST_CONTEXT_ATTR` I am using PrimeFaces 4.0 JSF 2.0. How do I decide it please suggest me.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `org.primefaces.util.Constants.REQUEST_CONTEXT_ATTR` had been remaining since PrimeFaces 3.5 was released and it was removed as of PrimeFaces 4.0.

Comment: So what do i need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect something strange must be going on in your code, e.g. your update logic not running behind the faces servlet.

The RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(), is the correct API to use if you wish to get the primefaces RequestContext instance that is active to an ongoing incoming JSF request.

If you are getting a NullPointer exception there, it would appear as if the FacesContext has not been enriched with the RequestContext from primefaces.

I  would assume this should not happen. YOu should cross check the compatibility of the Primefaces version you are using with the container you are running.
E.g primefaces 3.5 is OK for JEE6, primefaces 4.0 I have no idea.

Primefaces 6.0 is ok for JEE7, etc...

If you do something like FacesCOntext.getCurrentInstance() do you blow up?
If so this would be an indication you are trying to do update logic without having faces context active for your thread context.
E.g. you cannot access the faces context from an Mdb.
Or a Timer Poll(). Be careful there.

Finaly, I believe that constant you have posted has been taken away from the Constants of primefaces.

They have encapsulated it into the RequestContext object itself.

Here is a snipet of code from primefaces 6.0 that I am looking at right now:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2009-2014 PrimeTek.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.primefaces.context;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.api.AutoUpdatable;
import org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder;
import org.primefaces.util.CSVBuilder;
import org.primefaces.util.StringEncrypter;
import org.primefaces.util.WidgetBuilder;

/**
 * A RequestContext is a helper class consisting of several utilities.
 * RequestContext is thread-safe and scope is same as FacesContext.
 * Current instance can be retrieved as;
 * <blockquote>
 *  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
 * </blockquote>
 */
public abstract class RequestContext {

    private static final ThreadLocal<RequestContext> INSTANCE = new ThreadLocal<RequestContext>();

    public static final String INSTANCE_KEY = RequestContext.class.getName();

    public static RequestContext getCurrentInstance() {

        RequestContext context = INSTANCE.get();

        // #6503 - it's valid that a FacesContext can be released during the request
        // Our PrimeFacesContext therefore will only release our ThreadLocal cache
        // The RequestContext will be destroyed automatically if the FacesContext and it's attributes will be destroyed
        if (context == null) {
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            if (facesContext != null && !facesContext.isReleased()) {
                context = (RequestContext) facesContext.getAttributes().get(INSTANCE_KEY);
                if (context != null) {
                    INSTANCE.set(context);
                }
            }
        }

        return INSTANCE.get();
    }
```

So the conclusion is, they still put the RequestCOntext into the FacesContext attributes, but the constant that they use to read the faces context attributes now is this INSTANCE_KEY.

```
facesContext.getAttributes().get(INSTANCE_KEY)
```

The question is not what constant to use, but why your getCurrentInstance() is breaking.
THat normally indicates the JSF APIs are not being used behind a faces request.

Kind regads.

Comment: Thanks for an extensive answer, but I'd personally have asked if `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` did work. For all we know, OP is trying to access this outside a jsf request and that in an older version then 6.0 this using the RequestContext would have trown an NPE

Comment: Hi there, I agree. But I did ask if FacesContext could even be obtained. Quote the post above: "If you do something like FacesCOntext.getCurrentInstance() do you blow up?..." I

Comment: sorry ;-) Missed that part